# Android Google Map and Markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm asking because I heard about some issues for some users which are using my Application. I was already thinking about what it could be but didn't found a pattern behind the error to fix it afterwards. So I thought about asking you maybe someone could help me to figure it out.

The application is about taking information from a server and retrieving this back in a JSON format. This JSON is then parsed inside the Android application and the extracted information are visualised on the Google Map. The extracted information are latitude/longitude/marker description ...

For some markers typically the same, I heard until now that 2 out of 20 markers, are not visualised for a few users.

Does anyone know why this is happening? The users have either a

- Smartphone: Wiko Rainbow Version 8     / Version: 4.4.2
- Smartphone: Xperia Z1 Compact (D5503)  / Version: 5.1
- Smartphone: Galaxy S6 Edge+            / Version: 6.0
- Smartphone: Xperia Z3 (D6603)          / Version: 5.1

Best Regards,

Christophe

Comment: please add code sinnpt

Comment: Which code parts are you interest in? The download or the visualisation on the map, because how can it be possible that some markers are visualised some not? I already thought that these markers may have an encoding problem due to some special characters in the description but this isn't the case.

Comment: the visualisation on the map.

Comment: also when testing these kind of stuff make sure the markers are far from each other

Comment: Ok will do this as fast I can, but it probably will be in the afternoon, because it is a free time project and I am currently busy the complete day, but thanks so far when I am at home I will post the interesting part here. 

With far from each other, what is far (in meters) ? One of the markers which have sometimes  a problem is around 2km (bee line) away from another marker, but the other "problem" marker is far far away from another marker. Around every marker there is also a circle drawn (like a radius)

Comment: i usually make a couple of km between each other just to clearly test ,and with the actual data i use clustering so i dont get confused about the number of markers . waiting for the code :)

Comment: I will to it as fast as I can :) thanks for your attention. Maybe in the mean time I can try to explain you the procedure.

I'm running over an array list and putting for each value in the list a marker on the map. These marker could have different icons for the marker depending what category it is and this is it already^^ Nevertheless, I will post the code later on.

Typically there are not many markers around and those who are on their position should be visualised explicitly, therefore grouping or clustering is no opinion for my use case :/

Comment: as long as the marker dont have a null value as a marker-postion it should be drawn

Comment: Therefore, they should be there :) what very tricky is that for most of the user it works but not for all of them ^^

Comment: Ok I found the error -.- It was nothing with placing markers. The problem was that on few devices, sometimes not everything was downloaded from the server. So not every marker was placed...But now its working.